# Understanding more about solving inequalities

Tags: inequality

I solved this question : 
$$5x / (x^2+6) \le 1$$

Case 1 $\to$ $x^2+6>0$ 
or Case 2 $\to$ $x^2+6<0 $

Case 1  $x^2+6>0$
($x$ belongs to real number for some reason)

$$5x \leq x^2+6$$

$$0\le x^2-5x-16$$

$$(x-3)(x-2)\ge0$$

Case 1 a)

$x\geq 3$ or $x \geq 2$

so it is $x\geq 3$

case 1 b)

$x\leq3$ or $x\leq 2$

so it is $x\leq2$

Case 2 $$x^2+6<0$$ (no solution, it will always $\ge6$)

ans: $$x\leq2 , x\geq3$$

But it is unclear getting $x^2 + 6 > 0$ , $x$ belongs to real number

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question such that it is more readable.

Comment: After 27 posts, maybe you should spend some time learning how to format posts here?

Comment: haha sorry, i will spend time this weekend and learn, a bit tight schedule, thanks for the advice

Comment: If you try finding for what real numbers $x^2+6 > 0$, you will get the answer that it works for all reals.  Hence...

Comment: More clearly formatted: because $x^2 + 6 > 0$ for all real numbers $x$, you can multiply it by both sides without changing the inequality. Then you just have to solve the inequality $5x \leq x^2+6$. In my precalc class we taught how to do this using a "table of signs" method, though it can be done without this.

Comment: ^ Macavity, how do i know it is all reals like i move 6 to other side x^2 > -6 ....

Comment: @carry $6$ is positive and the square of something is never negative, so their sum is positive. The square is never negative because positive times positive = positive, negative times negative = positive. Zero times zero = zero, but that's not a problem in this case because of the $+6$.

Comment: i see, use common sense thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inequalities are not defined when talking about complex numbers so x has to be a real number otherwise the equation does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand your question, what is unclear ???
$ x^2 + 6 $ will always be greater than 6 as x is a real number and its square will always be a positive no. Also, note that inequalities are only defined for real numbers, e.g. $ i > 1 $ doesn't makes any sense

Comment: He's asking how do we know x is a real number

Comment: @RowanS I'm not sure whether he's asking how we know that $x$ is real or that $x^2+6>0$ holds for all reals.

Comment: ^ yeap sorry for being not clear, but just not quite sure how calculator says solution for x^2 + 6 > 0 is x belongs to real number

Comment: Oh well the answer is because x^2 + 6 is greater than 0 for all x . As (-x)^2=x^2. You should edit your question to make it clearer for other users.

Comment: You're a bit wrong: "$x^2+6$ will always be greater than _or equal to_ $6$ as $x$ is a real number and its square will always be a _non-negative_ no."